# Computing (the number) of paths in a directed graph starting from the initial state

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

(This is related to one of my academic projects)

Given a directed graph $G=(V,E)$, and $s_1\in V$ the initial state, Let's call a **primitive path** a path starting from the initial state and does not contain any edge twice (hence no loops)

we call a **maximal primitive path** a primitive path which is not a sub-path of another primitive path.

Example:
 [image]

(Here the initial state is $0$)

- A primitive path in the graph above should always start by $01$
- $012563$, $0123$ and $015$ are primitive paths
- $0125634$ and $01234$ are maximal primitive paths

My questions are :

> **Question1** How many maximal primitive paths are there approximately in a graph using big O notation with parameters $|V|$ and $|E|$. (we can assume that |V| and |E| are very large, and in case of difficulty we can also assume the density of the the graph to be very small or $|E|\sim Const |V|$ )

for the example above the answer is $3$ ($01234$,$0125634$,$015634$)

The number of primitive paths is larger than $|T|$ and we can find some graphs in which it's exactly $|T|$, and some graphs in which it's approximately $e(|V|)!$ where $e\sim 2.71828...$. Now if we add maximality there are some graphs in which the answer is $1$ and others for which it's $|V|!$.

Now if we assume the density to be small, I don't know how to handle the problem.

> **Question2** How can we generate all maximal primitive paths efficiently?

Comment: There might be exponentially many maximal primitive paths - just take $n$ copies of $\{(0,1),(0,2),(1,3),(2,3)\}$ and connect each $3$ to the next $0$. Each such a feature generates two valid choices.

Comment: Yes that's what I explained in my comment for the first answer, but the question is : can it be reduced if we assume the density of the graph to be very small?

Comment: What do you mean by small density? That example has $O(|V|)$ edges, which is usually considered sparse already.

Comment: Okay, yes you are absolutely right, I was asking a dump question

Comment: That would be considered as an answer to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be exponentially many maximal primitive paths – just take $n$ copies of graph given by $$V = \{0,1,2,3\},\quad\quad E = \{(0,1),(0,2),(1,3),(2,3)\},$$
and connect each $3$ to the next $0$ like this:
$$
\begin{array}
{}&        &1&&&&1\\
  &\nearrow&&\searrow&&\nearrow&&\searrow\\
0 &        &&&3\to\cdots\to 0 &&&& 3\\
  &\searrow&&\nearrow&&\searrow&&\nearrow\\
  &        &2&&&&2
\end{array}
$$
Each such a feature generates two valid choices. Such a graph has $O(|V|)$ edges, so it is sparse. Hence, unless you assume some special representation, generating all the possibilities seems impossible to do efficiently.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$